# 'The Java JAR file "NetC.jar" could not be launched.'

Tags: java, macos, jar, powerpc

```
Mac PowerPC OSX 10.5
```

I am trying to open a `.jar file` for my `PPC` but I keep getting the **error**:

> The Java JAR file "NetC.jar" could not be launched.'

I also downloaded `Java 5`.

I even went to "`Java Preferences`" and made sure it was set to `Java 5`. I rebooted the `PPC` as well.

Below is the error I get when I try to run this command in a terminal:

> salvador-castros-power-mac-g4:netc-0.2.0 becky$ java -jar NetC.jar
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad
>   version number in .class file     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:775)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:160)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:254)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:280)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:375)
>   salvador-castros-power-mac-g4:netc-0.2.0 becky$

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out my Mac OSX 10.5 PPC needs Java 6.... WHICH DOES NOT EXIST FOR THE PPC >_<